# Best in Place and jQuery: how to reload dom elements after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, best-in-place

I have a Rails 4 to-do list app where when I check the task checkbox, the form is automatically sent and the task is then added to the proper list (complete or incomplete tasks). This code looks like this:

```
# Task: Remove update buttons and listens to checkbox
jQuery.fn.submitOnCheck = ->
 @find('input[type=submit]').remove()
 @find('input[type=checkbox]').click ->
   $(this).parent('form').submit()
 this

jQuery ->
 $('.edit_task').submitOnCheck()
```

This is pretty sweet, but I am having troubles doing something similar with my [best in place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) fields. What I want is when the best in place field for the task deadline is successfully updated, the lists are reloaded so that the task can be moved to the list today tasks or future tasks depending on the deadline set. I tried this without success:

```
$('.deadline').bind("ajax:success", ->
  $(this).parent('form').submit())
```

If instead of a best in place field, I use a normal form_for field, this already works (when I press enter after changing the deadline, it goes to the appropriate list based on the date). But I want to use best in place because I don't want the field to be an edit field. I guess I could use javascript to hide/show the field on click, but I am very noob in this and I could not make it work.

Anyone know any ways to do this (one way or another)? I did manage to get it working having a full body reload with `location.reload()`, but that is ugly and slow.

[The repo is on Github](https://github.com/sergioschuler/prioriter) if you need to check specifics.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Best In Place, but after a cursory look at the docs, it seems that you do have the correct syntax for setting up an ajax success callback.  Now the crux of your question lies in how to "reload the lists".  But, you haven't provided nearly enough detail for anyone to answer that question.

Comment: I added the github repo in case you wanted to check out, because I believe adding a lot of the code here will only make things more confusing - unless you have a specific part you want to see? If I don't use best in place (so I use a normal form_form field for the deadline, it already works, but then it is hard to make the in place editing thing).

Comment: Just so you know, I was recently chewed out by SO members for posting my code in an external link.  Their point was, an external link will not always be available so this question won't have archival quality.  The best practice is to create a simplified use case illustrating the problem/task in jsFiddle or JS Bin.

Comment: In any case, are you using some sort of MVC framework?  How do you normally render the list?  From a server-side postback, or via AJAX?

Comment: I am using Rails 4 (weird, I forgot to tag it or it was removed). I am loading the list when the controller hits the index action in the Task controller. I am also using ajax (even though I barely know what it means) so the list reloads when I create a new action (so the action can go to the "todays tasks" or "future tasks" list.

Comment: Since I am using Rails 4, I am not sure how I could make a jsFiddle. I believe the real issue about posting code here is that I have no clue of what might be useful, because I am a very beginner that mostly is putting stuff together through tutorials and SO answers that not always are very clear on why. So I am flying a bit blind.

Comment: Ok, well unfortunately I've never used Ruby On Rails so I guess I won't be much help.  I was about to suggest that you add the ruby tag to your question, but I noticed you just did.  That should help attract people who are more qualified to help.